# CSS In DNN Modules

Tags: dotnetnuke

How could i include the custom css & JavaScript for particular module in DotnetNuke?

I understand that it is not like normal ASP.Net page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your module has a file named `module.css` in the root of the module folder, it will automatically get included on the page with the module.

For other CSS and for JavaScript, you should use the [Client Resource Management framework](http://bdukes.github.com/Making-Full-Use-of-the-Client-Resource-Management-Framework/#/title) to include the resources you want.  Something like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" 
    Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" 
    Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
 
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server"
    FilePath="~/DesktopModules/MyModule/css/the-style.css" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server"
    FilePath="~/DesktopModules/MyModule/js/the-script.js"
    ForceProvider="DnnFormBottomProvider" />
```

Comment: Hi! I found your answer about the DnnCssInclude and used it and it works almost perfectly. I do however have a slight problem and I was wondering if you could help out.
My case: I have a control that contains an asp.net wizard and I use a custom css for the wizard. When it loads for the first time some of the css (not all) does not load correctly (check screenshot here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0293xq5k49). When I click on a button the page does a postback and then the css is applied correctly (check screenshot here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0773xq5t90). Any thoughts?

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos I think that if some of the CSS is loading, it's probably a conflict with something else on the page, rather than an issue with how you're loading your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ControlPath %>/module.css" />
```

Answer (score -2):

To add external JavaScript to a custom module:

```cs
string externaJs= "externaJs";
Type cstype = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetType();
string cstext = "<script src=\"" +
                ResolveUrl("~/DesktopModules/ModuleName/js/JsName.js") +
                "\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";

if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(externaJs))
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, externaJs, cstext, false);
```

Comment: This is very manual and won't scale well. DNN has an API to do the same thing using the Client Dependency Framework to allow for minimization, aggregation, and caching, with less code, more code re-usability, and with better ability to scale.